Content inside CollapsingToolbarLayout is not showing in my Fragment
I am trying to implement a CollapsingToolbarLayout inside a Fragment using XML. However, the content inside my CollapsingToolbarLayout is not showing up. I am using AppBarLayout, Toolbar, and CollapsingToolbarLayout in my layout.
Here is my XML code for the fragment:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.HomeFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/loader_layout"
        layout="@layout/layout_circular_loader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="2dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                    android:text="Delivering to"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="->"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinssemibold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Gurugram"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                
                <include
                    layout="@layout/layout_search_bar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_width="44dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_bar_background"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris viverra urna eu gravida hendrerit..."
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


However, only color  inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout is displaying with the data is hidden or overlap not know exactly. I also tried adjusting the scroll flags and using different layout heights, but nothing seems to work. Is there something wrong with my layout, or am I missing something?
Also here is my theme for reference
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.TakeOut" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
<!--        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>-->
        <item name="colorSecondary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceContainer">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.TakeOut" parent="Base.Theme.TakeOut" />


</resources>


Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
i am expecting the content inside the collapsing toolabaar

The CollapsingToolbarLayout is meant to wrap the Toolbar. It's not a separate toolbar-type View on its own. The only thing it does, really, is handle the collapsing animation stuff. It's rather tedious to set up, but there's an official example here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TopAppBar.md#collapsing-top-app-bars.

hi, i want some content to be displayed inside the collapsing toolbar in the red area. is there any way to achieve that

I don't know what the red part is, but the <AppBarLayout> is a vertical LinearLayout, so you can put other things inside it alongside the <CollapsingToolbarLayout>, which should have the <Toolbar> inside of it.
